# How to get the encoded numbers in webpage?

Tags: python, scrape

I want to get the numbers in red color in the webpage but I got encoded string.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get('https://m.3fang.com/3f/land/zpg/detail/fc8e0948-2a63-449b-886b-2a54269b1498/b/370724.html', headers={'user-agent':'abc'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.find('p',{'class':'imp-num'}).text)
```

Instead of `2491.00`, I got `'\U000de4f7\U000da5fb\U000d4dfa\U000d1fae.\U000d7c4e\U000d7c4e㎡\n            '`.

How to get the correct numbers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extracting correct data from the page but the problem is with data rendering because of a missing font family. Scraped data has some Unicode characters that are not commonly available in most common font families.
So, you can view this data correctly by installing the same font that is being used by this site.

From the chrome developer tools, you can easily identify that site is using the following two URLs to link the fonts:

- https://industrydown1.fang.com/node-3fang-wap/1.2.6/font/my_default_c.580b51a2.ttf
- https://industrydown1.fang.com/node-3fang-wap/1.2.6/font/my_default_a.6ce68cf0.ttf

Just download these fonts and install them on the system where you want to visualize this data and if you intend to use it on a web page, you need to link these fonts in your stylesheets.

To install these fonts on my arch Linux, I downloaded these files and copied them to `~/.local/share/fonts/`. And then I executed the `fc-cache` command to update fonts cache on my system.

After installing these fonts I added that font as a fallback font on Visual Studio Code editor after which I am able to see these characters rendered properly. Attached a screenshot for reference:

[image]

For PyCharm, navigate to `File` > `Settings`. There search for `Console Font` or navigate to `Editor` > `Color Scheme` > `Console Font`. There set `my_default_c` as your fallback font and tick the option `Enable font ligatures`. Now, execute this script from Pycharm, it will load the proper fonts in console output as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me how to find the two urls?

Comment: yeah, sure. In Chrome, launch developer tools and then navigate to the `network` tab. There is a filter bar where you can click on the `font` filter to show only font URLs used for the site.

Comment: I installed the fonts in Windows 10. After restarting, I re-executed my code and I still got `'\U000fe3fe\U000f3edb\U000f8e3b\U000fb3e7.\U000f0c4d\U000f0c4d㎡\n            '`

Comment: you need to set this font as a fallback font in the editor/console where you are trying to visualize it. You can set it in Pycharm as well. Let me update the answer with proper steps for Pycharm.

Comment: It really works. Thank you, zahid. How to solve the problem for Python IDLE editor?